# Log4j2: custom plugin not working after switchign to Routing

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I was using a custom plugin registered programatically using the PluginManager class to load values in map and change the fileName of my RollingFileAppender based on the content of the map.

I then changed my config to use a Routing appender to be able to use the ThreadContext content to alter the fileName further (basically, I wanted to have one log file per thread of my application).

However, since I started using the Routing appender, my custom plugin is not yielding the desired results anymore although I didn't change it at all. Basically, it's returning empty values.

My log4j2-configuration.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="debug"/>
        </Console>

        <Routing name="contextSpecificAppender">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:threadName}">
                <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has no value for key threadName -->
                <Route key="$${ctx:threadName}">
                    <RandomAccessFile
                        name="applicationAppender"
                        fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/${propertymap:warName}.log"
                        filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/${propertymap:warName}.%i.log"
                        append="true"
                    >
                        <PatternLayout>
                            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%p} %style{[%t]}{magenta} %style{%c{1}:%L}{cyan,bold} - %m%n</Pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBaseTriggeringPolicy />
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
                        </Policies>
                        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1" />
                    </RandomAccessFile>
                </Route>
                <Route>
                    <RandomAccessFile
                        name="${ctx:threadName}"
                        fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/${propertymap:warName}-${ctx:threadName}.log"
                        filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/${propertymap:warName}-${ctx:threadName}.%i.log"
                        append="true"
                    >
                        <PatternLayout>
                            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %highlight{%p} %style{[%t]}{magenta} %style{%c{1}:%L}{cyan,bold} - %m%n</Pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBaseTriggeringPolicy />
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
                        </Policies>
                        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1" />
                    </RandomAccessFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="contextSpecificAppender" />
            <!--<AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>-->
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.axis2.enterprise" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="contextSpecificAppender" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="de.hunsicker.jalopy.io" level="fatal">
            <AppenderRef ref="contextSpecificAppender" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="httpclient.wire.header" level="fatal">
            <AppenderRef ref="contextSpecificAppender" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.apache.commons.httpclient" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="contextSpecificAppender" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The class that is responsible for loading the map is here:

```java
package com.my.package;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager;

/**
 *
 * @author ixm
 */
public class Log4jInitiliazer {
    public static void initialize(String warName, URL log4jProperties) {
        PropertyMapLookup.propertyMap.put("warName", warName);

        PluginManager.addPackage(PropertyMapLookup.class.getPackageName());

        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        try {
            context.setConfigLocation(log4jProperties.toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and it's called from a ServletContextListener:

```java
Log4jInitiliazer.initialize(warName, servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2-configuration.xml"));
```

Finally, the plugin itself is here:

```java
package com.my.package;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.StrLookup;

/**
 *
 * @author ixm
 */
@Plugin(name="propertymap", category=StrLookup.CATEGORY)
public class PropertyMapLookup implements StrLookup {
    public static Map<String, String> propertyMap = new HashMap();

    @Override
    public String lookup(String arg0) {
        return propertyMap.getOrDefault(arg0, "");
    }

    @Override
    public String lookup(LogEvent arg0, String arg1) {
        return propertyMap.getOrDefault(arg0, "");
    }

}
```

The resulting log file names are all "/var/log/tomcat9/-theNameOfTheThread.log" and it should instead be "/var/log/tomcat9/theNameOfTheWar-theNameOfTheThread.log".

I've tried several things that did not help :

- using the packages attribute for the Configuration tag of the log4j2-configuration.xml
- disabling the autoInitialization using a context param in the web.xml (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html)

For now, I've resorted to deploy the application in tomcat using a xml file that includes a context parameter that is accessible using ${web:initParam.warName} but that is not really practical for me.

Is there maybe an embedded way to retrieve the name of the war that is being deployed without having to even use a "custom" parameter approach?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried ${web:contextPath}?  While there is no guarantee that the context path will match the name of your war they would match by default in Tomcat. Where are you getting the value of warName from in your ServletContextListener?

Comment: @rgoers I actually found out about contextPath a few minutes after posting my question. Indeed, this solves the global issue but I still don't understand why the plugin was not working anymore. I'll leave the question up for a few days, if there's no answer, I'll invite you to post your comment as an answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that when it stopped working it is rcreating a file named "-threadId.log" indicates that your lookup is being called. If it wasn't the file name would be "${propertyMap:warName}-threadId.log". So this means either the warName you are storing is wrong or something is wrong with your Lookup. I can think of two possibilities.

1. You don't show how the war name is derived. It is possible something is wrong there.
2. It is possible your Lookup is present in 2 different classloaders. If this were to happen you would be initializing one in the servlet context initializer but using the other when logging.

if it was me, I would debug and make sure the same Map is being used when the war name is added and when it is being looked up.

As I noted in my comment above, you can also use the web lookup's contextPath key as ${web:contextPath}. That won't always be the same as the war name but it should be the same in a default Tomcat environment.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer because I did indeed end up using the web.contextPath variable. The war name is computed elsewhere and I verified that the value is correct using a simple system.out.println which was shown in the syslog. However, the same Log4jInitializer class is used by multiple war files deployed in the same tomcat. I'm still unsure how the class loader works exactly so maybe that has an incidence? Thank you for your help!